# pythonの配列にdatetime型のデータを入力したい

Tags: python

質問が不明瞭なままで申し訳ありませんでした

pythonの配列にpsqlに格納したdatetime型のデータを入力しようとすると、最初の一つ目は入るにもかかわらず、二つ目以降は型が違うと言われて入らなくなってしまいます

以下ソースです。

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*- 
# -*-coding:unicode-*- 
import csv 
import binascii 
import string 
import psycopg2 
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime as dt 

connection = psycopg2.connect("(省略)") 
connection.get_backend_pid() 

cur = connection.cursor() 
# SQLコマンド実行 (今回はテーブル作成) 
try: 
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE table(id serial,date date,time time,idm text,deviceid);") 
    print'ファイルを作成しました' 
except Exception as IOError: 
    print'ファイルが見つかりました' 
connection.commit() 

i = 0 
cur.execute("select*from table") 
#日付の記入 
now = 0 
count =0 
for row in cur: 
if not now==row[1]: 
print now,row[1],count 
date = (row[1]) #配列の作成
for l in range(count): 
    try: 
        print row[1],date[l],l  
    except Exception as e: 
        break 
    if now!=0 and row[1] == date[l]: 
        break 
    count = count +1 
    count_max =count 
    date = date + row[1]　#配列への追加(ここでエラーが出る)  
    now = row[1] 
    active[row[3],row[1]]=1
```

エラーメッセージ：

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "actable.py", line 43, in <module> 
date = date + row[1] 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and　'datetime.date'
```

型が違うと言われても同じ型のはずなので解決策が全く分かりません

Comment: 配列というのは listのことですか? arrayモジュールやnumpy.array のような本当の配列ですか? 情報がこれだけでは、エスパーではないのですから、プログラムがなにか間違っているんでしょう、以外のアドバイスはできませんよ。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ もしよければ、この問題に関係していそうなソースコードを質問文に転記してくださいませんか？　自分の質問には「編集」から自由に追記できます。

Comment: ソース部分がわかりやすいように編集しましたが、インデントがよくわからないので (推測は出来ますが) ご自分で編集しなおしていただけますか。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。修正いたしました

Comment: ちなみにエラーの意味は、`+` は datetime.date 同士の計算をサポートしていない、ということです。日付同士を足しても意味がないからでしょう。

Comment: まだインデントに違和感があります（`for row in cur:`以降）。これで正しいですか？

Comment: 遅れて申し訳ありません、皆様のおかげで解決しました。
ありがとうございます

Comment: @kanadekatahira お疲れ様でした。こちら、quiquiさんの回答で解決したということでしょうか？　もしそうでしたら、是非[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)して頂けませんでしょうか。回答の横の緑のマークを押せばOKです。ご自身の力で解決したということであれば、是非[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんか？

Answer (score 2):

コードの意図を読めていませんが、推測だと、

```
date = (row[1])
```

の部分でやりたかったことは

```
date = [row[1]]
```

ではなかったでしょうか?

`(row[1])` の括弧は演算の優先度変更の括弧だとされるので、意味を持たない冗長な記述になっています。

あと

```
date = date + row[1]
```

も

```
date = date + [row[1]]
```

もしくは

```
date.append(row[1])  #こちらの方がよい
```

ですね。